# TIMESTAMPDIFF Function on DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on `DB2`

My question is in two parts:

First when I try to use it on two timestamp one of them have some null values it give me the following error:

> "SCE1.TIMESTAMP" is not valid in the context where it is used..
>   SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.16.53"

`SCE1.TIMESTAMP` is the column that have null values, is there a way that function works only on the timestamp values and ignore the nulls in that column?

Second that `TIMESTAMPDIFF` calculate as following:

```
One year has 365 days
One year has 52 weeks
One year has 12 months
One month has 30 days
One day has 24 hours
One hour has 60 minutes
One minute has 60 seconds
```

I was wondering if there way to make it more accurate for example if both timestamps exceed between month from 28 days ("Feb") to month 31 days ("March") the results won't be accurte because the function know month as 30 days, is there way to get over that.

Comment: Which platform/version of db2, and critically, what about timezones??  Note that you can't use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)` to get an accurate picture because of one major problem - the _input_ to the function is a (string representation of a) relative interval; something like `'00100302140121'` (`'0010'` years, `'03'` months, `'02'` days, `'14'` hours, `'01'` minute, `'21'` seconds).  Except to know how long a year (or month) is, you need to know what you started from.  `TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)` is fundamentally broken.  What are you trying to do with this information, there may be ways around it.

Comment: ....your application-layer language may have better tools to perform this math (if you need the information).  Otherwise, you're going to have to write (and test) an equivalent function to get accurate results.

Comment: There is no way to make TIMESTAMPDIFF() work differently. And in order for us to know much about why you're getting the error, we first have to see what statement is throwing the error as well as see the definitions of the involved columns. Until we see what you're working with, we can't guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Only calculate the function when neither item is null.

```
case when stamp1 is null then null
     when stamp2 is null then null
     else timestampdiff( stamp1, stamp2 )
end
```

**2)** This has been answered before, including by me.  Search and you should find.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer Sir
I got the following error when running it :
"

No authorized routine named "TIMESTAMPDIFF" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.16.53
"
2)I searched for your posts but they too many is there some words that i can search for to determine the post fast.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: @Warrant `TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)` for DB2 doesn't take two timestamps as input.